# Persist clipboard contents in vi

Tags: vim

If I want to copy text from a file in `vi` to another file, I have to highlight the text, <kbd>Control-Shift-C</kbd> it, quit the first file, open the second, and then paste it via <kbd>Control-Shift-V</kbd>. It feels like there must be an easier way to do this - that is, keyboard commands only. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While editing a file you can use `:e filename` to open another file and `:rew` to return to the original file like this:

1. open original file `vi foo`
2. yank text e.g. `yy` (yank a line)
3. open a second file to edit `ESC :e bar`
4. put your text `p` (then save `:w`)
5. go back to the first file `ESC :rew`

Comment: personally I like using vim's tabs... e.g. `:tabe filename` then using `gt` to switch tabs. also you can enter visual mode with `v` then use `y` to yank multiple lines. or use `m'y` (mark for beginning of yank) and `yy` to yank multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

vim can be set up with X clipboard support. Pass --with-x=yes to configure if your distribution does not bundle vim with X support. By default the X clipboard is available as the * buffer and the X cut board (selection) is available as the " buffer, so selecting a region and typing `"+y` will yank the selection to the X cut board, and `"*y` will yank to the X clipboard. Similarly, `"*p` will paste from the X clipboard and `"+p` from the X selection.

You can set the default (anonymous) buffer in vim to be the X clipboard by running `set clipboard=unnamed`. Then you can just `y` and `p` from the X clipboard directly.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

1. Open your file: `vi foo`
2. In your file, open the second: <kbd>ESC :open bar</kbd>
3. Return to the first: <kbd>ESC :prev</kbd>
4. To copy the content of the file: <kbd>ESC :1,$ y</kbd>
5. To go the next file: <kbd>ESC :n</kbd>
6. Paste it: <kbd>ESC p</kbd>

Maybe there's a shorter way?